# Can we observe apsidal precession in a two-body system following only Newton's gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I recently used Octave to simulate a 2-body system, following Newton's gravitation only(pictures of output at the end). However, I was surprised to observe apsidal precession of the orbits. Is this supposed to happen in Newtonian gravity ? I also read somewhere that if the inverse square law varies slightly differently(like 1.998 instead of 2 in the power), apsidal precession is observed. Since I am basically using the powers of floats, the variation will not be exactly inverse square. Is this the reason for the observation ? Or is there a better reason ?

[image]

Note that the elliptic orbits shift. The starting positions are (-10,0) and (10,0) with equal and opposite velocity in the y directions only. Also, this is a simulation upto a finite time.

EDIT: I am only looking for a physical reason(if any). Please do not discard the question as 'not belonging to physics' or something like that.

Comment: For two isolated point particles interacting through Newtonian gravity there cannot be apsidal precession. According to Bertrand's Theorem the corresponding bound orbit is closed. The physical origin for precession in real systems can be given by perturbations such as the existence of other interacting particles, the oblateness of the  bodies and relativistic corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for numerical error to cause effects like this in simulations of gravitational models.  Set your tolerances, or your timesteps, or your lattice size, or whatever, lower and see if the effect diminishes.

Comment: I'm skeptical.  The results are very asymmetrical, but numerical errors shouldn't do that for a symmetrical system.

Comment: In particular, if the masses are supposed to be equal, every numerical error should be *precisely* canceled by a numerical error of the opposite sign.  So I would go so far as to say that you are incorrect when claiming that numerical errors causes "effects like this".

Comment: @Mike: discretization can cause random weird effects.  Just because the representation is symmetric does not mean that the computers underlying representation is.  Also, one of the other comments point out that the masses are not the same.  Anamolous precession is a very generic feature of computer simulations of Newtonian gravitational two-body problems, though.

Comment: I don't see any other comment about unequal masses (other than my answer).  All I see is the initial condition which is equal and opposite.  Given a reasonable underlying representation of that system, the numbers really should be identical, except for the flipped bit denoting opposite signs, in which case they should be able to cancel identically, leading to no asymmetry.  There will still be discretization errors, etc., but they will be symmetric for any reasonable implementation.  The numerical center of mass should remain *precisely* at the origin.

Comment: @Mike: I've done this before.  Floating point errors don't necessarily respect symmetry, because 0 will be represented as 1e-12 or truncation won't respect relative values of velocities and positions or something.  

Irrespectively, changing tolerances will settle this.

Comment: I've also done this before.  I understand floating point errors.  But when you have the symmetry that the OP's initial data and puzzlement suggest, if one is `1e-12` the other will be `-1e-12`, and they will cancel exactly *at the bit level*.  The `"f"` would have to be an insanely unstable representation of the physics for bad integrator tolerances to cause the level of error shown in that plot.  Moreover, there is a far more likely explanation: there is no precession, but the masses are significantly unequal, so symmetric initial data lead to a nonzero center-of-mass velocity.

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting your plots.  That's not apsidal precession; that's just a uniform drift in the $-y$ direction.

It looks like something in your code is giving these particles different masses, and since their *velocities* are equal and opposite, that means their *momenta* are not equal or opposite.  Instead, you get a center of mass that starts offset from the origin and net velocity that moves it farther away.

You can tell because you know where each "particle" starts.  The red one starts at $x=-10$ with velocity in the $-y$ direction.  As you follow it around, the next orbit is ***below*** the previous line.  The blue one starts at $x=+10$ with velocity in the $+y$ direction.  As you follow it around, the next orbit is ***also below*** the previous line.  If this were precession, one would be above and the other below.  (This would be clearer if you just plotted the first 1.4 orbits, say.)

But you can also see a pronounced asymmetry in the plots.  Look at where the blue line is after half an orbit, compared to where the red line is — the center of mass is clearly at some $-x$ value.

Thus, I am led to believe that there is some error in your coding.  You show us enough to suggest that the initial conditions are $(x_{1}, y_{1}, v_{x1}, v_{y1}, x_{2}, y_{2}, v_{x2}, v_{y2}, ) = (10, 0, 0, 2, -10, 0, 0, -2)$.  If the particles have equal mass, the center of mass should be at the origin and stay at the origin.  But your plots show that the center of mass starts out somewhere more like $(x, y) = (-1, 0)$, suggesting that the masses are related by something like $m_1 / m_2 = 9/10$.  But then the net momentum in the $y$ direction is $(2)m_1 + (-2)m_2 = (-1/5)m_2 < 0$, which explains the drift in the $-y$ direction.

I guess the question is: what is this `"f"` that you've given `lsode`?  My guess is that it doesn't really correspond to the evolution function for an equal-mass system.